# Netsuite - Transfer Inventory error

Tags: netsuite, transfer, inventory

I have been using NetSuite for only a short time, and already hate it. I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I haven't been able to find an answer so far, either in the Netsuite docs, StackOverflow or other websites. In fact, the answers I found have resulted in an error.

My company requires a script to transfer inventory based on an EDI input file. Reading the file is no problem, even parsing it is working. However, actually inserting the data is proving problematic.
I have been able to insert normal records, but Inventory Transfer records are giving me problems.

From Stack Overflow I found and adapted some code into the following:

```
var xfer = nlapiCreateRecord("inventorytransfer");

xfer.setFieldValue("trandate", FormatDate("20160101"));
xfer.setFieldValue("location", 9);
xfer.setFieldValue("transferlocation", 9);

nlapiSelectNewLineItem('invt');
nlapiSetLineItemValue("invt","invtid",1, 189);
nlapiSetLineItemValue("invt","adjustqtyby", 1, "5");
nlapiCommitLineItem('invt');

var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(xfer);
```

The FormatDate function just exchanges the date from the text file into a system date NetSuite can understand.

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

> USER_ERROR: You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.

I thought inserting the line item was the reason to use nlapiSelectNewLineItem, but I guess not. Also nlapiCreateNewLineItem doesn't seem to exist.

The values I am inserting are all just test data, as I'm testing this in the debugger. Location 9 exists, as does item 189.
My full script finds these id's based on string values from the text files. But since this is the section that doesn't work I have set it apart to test.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the type of script you are using, but, looks like you are not setting the fields on the record object, but, setting the value on current record. Below, is the suggested code.

Also, there is no sublist named `invt`, it should be `inventory`. Also, there is no field as such `invtid`, I think most probably you want to setup item, the field Id should be `item`. You might want to refer [SuiteScript Record Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/script/record/inventorytransfer.html) as well for a help on correct Ids

```
var xfer = nlapiCreateRecord("inventorytransfer");

xfer.setFieldValue("trandate", FormatDate("20160101"));
xfer.setFieldValue("location", 9);
xfer.setFieldValue("transferlocation", 9);

xfer.selectNewLineItem('inventory');
xfer.setCurrentLineItemValue("inventory", "item", 189);
xfer.setCurrentLineItemValue("inventory","adjustqtyby", "5");
xfer.commitLineItem('inventory');

var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(xfer);
```

If you are using Bin/Lot Numbered Items, please see help topic "Sample Scripts for Advanced Bin / Numbered Inventory Management"

Comment: Looks like you should also be using `xfer.setCurrentLineItemValue` without an index rather than `xfer.setLineItemValue`

Comment: Thank you @prasun for the fast reply. This script is written directly into the debugger. But the full script is a scheduled script for processing files each night. Unfortunately with this new code the same error appears.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh the same error with your suggestion. But thank you.

Comment: @AndrewHewitt Please see my edit and also, as @erictgrubaugh suggested, using `setCurrentLineItemValue` is a better way

Comment: @prasun Thank you. It seems 'inventory' rather than 'invt' was the main problem ('invt' came from a tutorial on this kind of transfer). I have marked this as the answer.
However, it has left me with a further error: "Please configure the inventory detail for this line." which I will investigate from now.

Comment: certain items need invetory details, for which you can find code in NetSuite help - "Inventory detail sub record", try searching with this keyword

Comment: i m having an error:
 "You must enter at least one line item for this transaction"

while doing the same as answered above. Can anybody tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: @4ni5 we are seeing that error too since 2020.2 upgrade even in SuiteScript 2.0 on certain items.

Comment: @prasun - thanks dear, at least i know this is not something from my side

Comment: @4ni5 that was a different error in our script, and is resolved and not from NS end. I would say you should try SuiteScript 2.0/2.1 to achieve the same.